# SQL Server 2016 partitioning with columnstore

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, sql-server-2016, columnstore

Environment is SQL 2016/SP1/CU1 Enterprise on Windows 2012 R2 Standard, and I'm running tests on using paritioning in combination with clustered columnstore.

For one large table (300 million rows), data was first sorted by a date column, bulk inserted into the partitioned table, and then a clustered columnstore index was created.

The data type for the partitioning column is date, and this column exists in the smaller parent table, and the larger partitioned table.

There are a few joins from the large table to other smaller tables.

When the predicate is:
WHERE parent.datecolumn BETWEEN @date1 and @date2

I see rowgroup elimination, but no partition elimination.

When the predicate is:
WHERE parent.datecolumn BETWEEN @date1 and @date2
  AND partitioned.datecolumn BETWEEN @date1 and @date2

I do not see rowgroup elimination, but I do see partition elimination.

I'm not sure if this is expected behavior, but didn't entirely make sense to me.

Comment: Also wanted to mention that in both cases, for the large table the columnstore index was used, with batch mode.